# Implement Interface by contract

Tags: c#, .net

i will show you a short example:

`public abstract class Foo { publi string Name {get;set;} }`

`public class SomeClass : Foo {}`

I use something like that and now i want that everyone who inherits from that Foo Class also implements a specific Interface by contract.

Is there any possibility?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You cant inherit from a sealed class. You have to change it to just "public sealed Foo"

Comment: Make `Foo` implement the interface? Also, that wouldn't compile since `Foo` is `sealed`

Comment: just a misstake... its a abstract class

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit from a sealed class. But if we change the "sealed" to "class" you will be able to achieve your goal by doing this:

```
public interface IAge {
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IAge {
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class SomeClass : Foo {
    public int GetAge(){
        return this.Age;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i mean abstract not sealed

Answer (score 0):

Add the interface and give it abstract implementations.

```
public ISomeInterface { void Bar() };

public abstract class Foo : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public abstract void Bar();
}
```

Now any class that inherits from `Foo` must also implement `Bar()`.